# Preventing Pressable activation when dragging FlatList in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using a a carousel library (that uses a FlatList) to drag things in React Native.

I've got this for the carousel:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-native-reanimated-carousel";
import Card from "components/cards/Card";

function CardCarousel(props) {
  return (
    <Carousel
      scrollAnimationDuration={200}
      width={300}
      windowSize={9}
      moveSize={5}
      style={{
        width: 2000,
        height: 300,
      }}
      data={props.articleGroup.data}
      renderItem={(article, index) => (
        <Card
          article={article.item}
          key={index + "-main-" + props.articleGroup.category}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

export default CardCarousel;
```

And then my card looks like this:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState(props.article.bookmark);
  const cdnURL = wrapImgCDN(props.article.image, 400);

  const routeChange = async (event) => {
    ... code to change route
  };

  const _bookmarkToggle = () => {
    bookmarkToggle(props.article);
    setBookmark(!bookmark);
  };

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPress={routeChange}
    >
      <WhiteCard
        {...props}
        _bookmarkToggle={_bookmarkToggle}
        cdnURL={cdnURL}
        bookmark={bookmark}
      />
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```

When I am dragging the FlatList, if I do so by grabbing onto one of the `<Card />` items, it clicks and changes the route to the given card, but I don't want to allow a user to click into a card unless the scrolling is stopped/the user didn't drag at all.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are wrapping the rendered items of the `carousel` into a `Pressable` and fire the `routeChange` in its `onPress` function, it will change the route as soon as you press one of the items in the carousel.

We could use the `onSnapToItem` callback function of the [react-native-reanimated-carousel](https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel/blob/main/docs/props.md) component instead. This function is passed as a prop to the component and will be called as soon as an item in the FlatList 'snaps'. It receives the index of the item that will be snapped. We can compare this with the current item and whenever it changes, we pass a boolean prop to the `Card` component.

The `current index` can be accessed using `ref` via the `getCurrentIndex` function as usual.

Notice that this needs an additional state. However, we only change the state if the item has actually changed, that is, a new item `snapped into position`.

The boolean state will be true for the current snapped item, and false for the other ones. We react on `fireRouteChange` prop changes in a `useEffect` in the `Card` component.

```js
function CardCarousel(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <Carousel
      ref={ref}
      onSnapToItem={(index) => index !== ref.current.getCurrentIndex() && setCurrentIndex(index)}
      scrollAnimationDuration={200}
      width={300}
      windowSize={9}
      moveSize={5}
      style={{
        width: 2000,
        height: 300,
      }}
      data={props.articleGroup.data}
      renderItem={(article, index) => (
        <Card
          article={article.item}
          fireRouteChange={currentIndex === index}
          key={index + "-main-" + props.articleGroup.category}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const Card = (props) => {
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState(props.article.bookmark);
  const cdnURL = wrapImgCDN(props.article.image, 400);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(props.fireRouteChange) {
       ... code to change route
    }
  }, [props.fireRouteChange])

  const _bookmarkToggle = () => {
    bookmarkToggle(props.article);
    setBookmark(!bookmark);
  };

  return (
      <WhiteCard
        {...props}
        _bookmarkToggle={_bookmarkToggle}
        cdnURL={cdnURL}
        bookmark={bookmark}
      />
  );
};
```

##### Assumption: The `routeChange` function can be located in `CardCarousel`

We can make this simpler if we assume that the `routeChange` function can be located in `CardCarousel`. I do not have access to the implementation details of this function, thus I include this here by making this assumption.

```js
function CardCarousel(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

 function routeChange(index) {

    ... code to change route of the current snapped index
 };

  return (
    <Carousel
      ref={ref}
      onSnapToItem={(index) => index !== ref.current.getCurrentIndex() && fireRouteChange(index)}
      scrollAnimationDuration={200}
      width={300}
      windowSize={9}
      moveSize={5}
      style={{
        width: 2000,
        height: 300,
      }}
      data={props.articleGroup.data}
      renderItem={(article, index) => (
        <Card
          article={article.item}
          fireRouteChange={currentIndex === index}
          key={index + "-main-" + props.articleGroup.category}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const Card = (props) => {
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState(props.article.bookmark);
  const cdnURL = wrapImgCDN(props.article.image, 400);

  const _bookmarkToggle = () => {
    bookmarkToggle(props.article);
    setBookmark(!bookmark);
  };

  return (
      <WhiteCard
        {...props}
        _bookmarkToggle={_bookmarkToggle}
        cdnURL={cdnURL}
        bookmark={bookmark}
      />
  );
};
```

##### Disable the `onPress` function while the user is scrolling

If you want to disable the `onPress` function while the user is scrolling and only allow it while the carousel is snapped in place, you can use a state and the `onScrollBegin` and `onScollEnd` functions.

```js
function CardCarousel(props) {

  const [allowRouteChange, setAllowRouteChange] = useState(true) 

  return (
    <Carousel
      scrollAnimationDuration={200}
      width={300}
      windowSize={9}
      moveSize={5}
      onScrollBegin={() => setAllowRouteChange(false)}
      onScrollEnd={() => setAllowRouteChange(true)}
      style={{
        width: 2000,
        height: 300,
      }}
      data={props.articleGroup.data}
      renderItem={(article, index) => (
        <Card
          allowRouteChange={allowRouteChange}
          article={article.item}
          key={index + "-main-" + props.articleGroup.category}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const Card = (props) => {
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState(props.article.bookmark);
  const cdnURL = wrapImgCDN(props.article.image, 400);

  const routeChange = async (event) => {
    if (props.allowRouteChange) {
           ... code to change route
    }
  };

  const _bookmarkToggle = () => {
    bookmarkToggle(props.article);
    setBookmark(!bookmark);
  };

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPress={routeChange}
    >
      <WhiteCard
        {...props}
        _bookmarkToggle={_bookmarkToggle}
        cdnURL={cdnURL}
        bookmark={bookmark}
      />
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I am displaying multiple items in the carousel at once (this library allows you to show multiple items), so users can select any from a number of different carousel items that might be visible to them (especially on the web, on larger viewports)

Comment: Use the `onScrollBegin` and `onScrollEnd` functions. I have included this in my answer.

Comment: Excellent! That seems like that works. I figured it had to be something simple I wasn't thinking of. Makes sense to just explicitly do it with state. Thank you!